# What exactly does "accuracy" mean in HTML5 geolocation?

Tags: html, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

When using the HTML5 geolocation API I get, apart from latitude and longitude, also the "accuracy of the location in meters". What exactly does that mean (meters is not a unit of accuracy)?

I assume it shall be read as "with probability *p* the request was made within *a* meters of the returned location" - if so, what is *p*? Is it one standard deviation (*p = 0.682*?) Two standard deviations (*p = 0.956*?)

http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html isn't really explicit either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting from the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#accuracy):

> The accuracy and altitudeAccuracy values returned by an implementation should correspond to a 95% confidence level.

So, 95% confidence level it is. Then again, implementations can vary significantly in what they report...

Comment: I guess it means that if we have an accuracy of R meters then any point in a circle of radius R meters centered in the referred point has a confidence level of 95%? My question is about R is the radius or the diameter of the circle? Also, its not clear to me if the confidence area shape is a circle or a rectangle.